# Data type of pandas column changes to object when it's passed to a function via apply?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to use the `dtype` of a pandas column in a function, but for some reason when I call the function using `apply`, the `dtype` is changed to `object`. Does anyone know what is happening here?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'stringcol':['a'], 'floatcol': [1.5]})
df.dtypes
Out[1]: 
floatcol     float64
stringcol     object
dtype: object

df.apply(lambda col: col.dtype)
Out[2]: 
floatcol     object
stringcol    object
dtype: object
```

Note that this problem doesn't happen if the column is passed directly:

```
f = lambda col: col.dtype
f(test.floatcol)
Out[3]: dtype('float64')
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears to be due to an optimization in `DataFrame._apply_standard`.  The "fast path" in the code of that method creates an output Series whose dtype is the dtype of `df.values`, which in your case is `object` since the DataFrame is of mixed type.  If you pass `reduce=False` to your `apply` call, the result is correct:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda col: col.dtype, reduce=False)
floatcol     float64
stringcol     object
dtype: object
```

(I must say that it is not clear to me how this behavior of `reduce` jibes with the documentation.)

Comment: nice one, i actually seem to remember a similar bug with `DataFrame.to_sql` ... I wonder if this 'optimisation' is problematic as default behaviour since pretty much every dataframe i use has mixed data types....

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with pandas 1.3.4, I get `TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reduce'`

Comment: @RishabhAgrahari: It looks like `apply` was changed so now it has a `result_type` argument instead of `reduce`.  But it also looks like it was changed so that the problem the question was asking about no longer exists (i.e., just using regular apply no longer coerces the column to object dtype).

Answer (score 1):

For pandas versions `v0.23+` the answer is:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.dtype, result_type='expand')
```

This works even though the Pandas documentation claims that the `result_type` argument "only act when `axis=1` (columns)"

credit @jezrael