# Why does apply change dtype in pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A = np.arange(3), 
                         B = np.random.randn(3), 
                         C = ['foo','bar','bah'], 
                         D = pd.Timestamp('20130101')))

print(df)

   A         B    C          D
0  0 -1.087180  foo 2013-01-01
1  1 -1.343424  bar 2013-01-01
2  2 -0.193371  bah 2013-01-01
```

`dtypes` for columns:

```
print(df.dtypes)
A             int32
B           float64
C            object
D    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

But after using [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) they all changes to object:

```
print(df.apply(lambda x: x.dtype))
A    object
B    object
C    object
D    object
dtype: object
```

Why are `dtypes` coerced to object? I thought that in `apply` only columns should be taken in account.

`pandas 0.17.1`
`python 3.4.3`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data type of pandas column changes to object when it's passed to a function via apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715287/data-type-of-pandas-column-changes-to-object-when-its-passed-to-a-function-via)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use parameter `reduce=False` and more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31715588/2901002):

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: x.dtype, reduce=False))

A             int32
B           float64
C            object
D    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

In newer versions of pandas is possible use:

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: x.dtype, result_type='expand'))
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't find that while searching.

Comment: Even though the pandas v1.0 + documentation claims the `result_type` arguments "only act when `axis=1` (columns)", this still seems to work for me (with `axis` left as default = 0)

Comment: Using an older version of Pandas, 0.16.2, `reduce=False` did not stop the `apply()` from casting my np.Int64 value as `int`.