# pandas apply changing dtype

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to convert a pandas dataframe into a Series of tuples:

#### Example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3.0],[3,4,5.0]])
```

#### Desired Output:

```
0    (1, 2, 3.0)
1    (3, 4, 5.0)
dtype: object
```

However pandas seems to coerce my integer columns to floats.

#### I tried

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3.0],[3,4,5]])
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
print(df.apply(tuple,axis=1,reduce=False).apply(str))
```

#### Actual output:

```
   0  1    2
0  1  2  3.0
1  3  4  5.0

0      int64
1      int64
2    float64
dtype: object

0    (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
1    (3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
dtype: object
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917404/why-does-apply-change-dtype-in-pandas-dataframe-columns) suggests using `reduce=False` but this doesn't change anything for me.

Could someone explain why pandas is coercing the datatype somewhere along the way?

Comment: Well, the *reason* for the coercion is `pd.DataFrame.apply` creates a series out of each row, which cannot be a series of `int` (as there's a `float`), so is upcasted to `float`. @pir has the fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `pandas.DataFrame.itertuples`

to avoid forcing your ints to floats

```
pd.Series([*df.itertuples(index=False)])

0    (1, 2, 3.0)
1    (3, 4, 5.0)
dtype: object
```

---

#### `zip`, `map`, splat... magic

```
pd.Series([*zip(*map(df.get, df))])

0    (1, 2, 3.0)
1    (3, 4, 5.0)
dtype: object
```

Comment: This looks super nifty.

Comment: Alternative: `df.astype(object).apply(tuple, axis=1)`

Answer (score 3):

Adding python2.7 compatible solution:

```
In [3]: pd.Series(tuple(i) for i in df.itertuples())
Out[4]:
0    (0, 1, 2, 3.0)
1    (1, 3, 4, 5.0)
dtype: object
```