# Pandas apply casts None dtype to object or float depending on other outputs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, dtype

I would like to control the output dtypes for *apply* on a row. *foo* and *bar* below have multiple outputs.

```
import pandas as pd

def foo(x):
    return x['a'] * x['b'], None, x['a'] > x['b']

def bar(x):
    return x['a'] * x['b'], None

df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 10, 'b': 2}, {'a': 10, 'b': 20}])
df2 = df.copy()
df[['product', 'dummy', 'greater']] = df.apply(foo, axis=1, result_type='expand')
df2[['product', 'dummy']] = df2.apply(bar, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

The output dtypes are:

| col | df | df2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | int64 | int64 |
| b | int64 | int64 |
| product | **int64** | **float64** |
| dummy | **object** | **float64** |
| greater | bool | - |

A comment to this question [pandas apply changing dtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52078594/pandas-apply-changing-dtype), suggests that apply returns a series with a single dtype. That may be the case with *bar* since the outputs can be cast to float. But it doesn't seem to be the case for *foo*, because then the outputs would need to be object.

Is it possible to control the output dtypes of apply? I.e. get/specify the output dtypes (int, object) for bar, or do I need to cast the dtype at the end?

Background:
I have a dataframe where the *dummy* column has values True, False and None and dtype 'object'. The apply function runs on some corner cases, and introduces NaN instead of None. I'm replacing the NaN with None after apply, but it seems overly complicated.

pandas version 1.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you're asking why `product` and `dummy` have different dtypes after applying `foo` and `bar` even though the values returned by those functions are the same for those new columns ?

```
       col      df      df2
0        a   int64    int64
1        b   int64    int64
2  product   int64  float64  # int64  <> float64
3    dummy  object  float64  # object <> float64
4  greater    bool
```

If so, that's because when `result_type == "expand"`, there is a specific transformation done behind the scenes with [`infer_to_same_shape`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.2/pandas/core/apply.py#L1053), which is roughly equivalent to this :

```
_datafoo = {0: (20, None, True), 1: (200, None, False)}
_databar = {0: (20, None), 1: (200, None)}

expandfoo = pd.DataFrame(_datafoo).T.set_axis(df.index).infer_objects()
expandbar = pd.DataFrame(_databar).T.set_axis(df.index).infer_objects()
```

**Output (*foo*) :**

```
print(expandfoo.T, expandfoo, expandfoo.dtypes.to_dict(), sep="\n"*2)

      0      1
0    20    200
1  None   None
2  True  False

     0     1      2
0   20  None   True
1  200  None  False

{0: dtype('int64'), 1: dtype('O'), 2: dtype('bool')}
```

**Output (*bar*) :**

```
print(expandbar.T, expandbar, expandbar.dtypes.to_dict(), sep="\n"*2)

      A      B
0  20.0  200.0
1   NaN    NaN  # <-- see the presence of NaN

       0   1
0   20.0 NaN
1  200.0 NaN

{0: dtype('float64'), 1: dtype('float64')}
```

As you can see, [`infer_objects`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html) keeps `expandbar` inferred as `float64` for both columns (if this is unintuitive, see [*GH28318*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28318)).

---

> *Is it possible to control the output dtypes of `apply` ?*

That depends on the computation made by the applied function and the values returned. So yes, you have somehow this kind of control but you can always add [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) or [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) at the end.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was wondering about. Does this mean that the apply output is dtype object by default

Comment: Not really. For example, expanding `foo` leads to a `product` column cast as `"int64"`. So, it depends on your data and the computation applied.

Comment: I see that you updated your post. Be aware of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I was trying to make the question as simple as possible. But I'll provide some background if I have a question again. Thanks again for your explanation.