# Pandas dataframe `apply` to `dtype` generates unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## Example

Toy dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['the', 'this'], 'b': [5, 2.3], 'c': [8, 11], 'd': ['the', 7]})
```

yields:

```
>>> df

      a    b   c    d
0   the  5.0   8  the
1  this  2.3  11    7
```

and:

```
>>> df.dtypes

a     object
b    float64
c      int64
d     object
dtype: object
```

---

## Problem Statement

But what I **really** want to do is perform `df.apply` so that I can perform some actions on values in a column **if that column/series is a string type**.

So I thought I could simply do something like:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: if x.dtype == 'object' and <the other check I care about>)
```

But it didn't work as I'd expected, everything was an `object`. To verify, try:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.dtype == 'object')
a    True
b    True
c    True
d    True
dtype: bool
```

Trying to understand what was going on, I tried the following:

```
>>> def tmp_fn(val, typ):
...   if val.dtype == typ:
...     print(type(val))
...     print(val.dtype)
```

and then

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: tmp_fn(x, 'object'))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
object
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
object
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
object
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
object
a    None
b    None
c    None
d    None
dtype: object
```

---

## Attempts at Understanding

Now I knew what was happening:  the pandas series was being interpreted as just that, a series.  Seemed easy to solve.

But, in fact, it wasn't working as a series normally works in other cases.  For instance, if I try:

```
>>> df.a.dtype
dtype('O')

>>> df.b.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Those both work as I expected and give me the type of object **inside** the series, instead of the simple fact that it is a series.

But try as I might, I couldn't figure out a way to replicate that same sort of behavior within `pandas.DataFrame.apply`.  What's going on here?  How can I get the series to act as it normally would?  In other words, how can I get a `pandas.DataFrame.apply` to work exactly as a `pandas.Series` would?  I never knew/realized they weren't acting identically until now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data type of pandas column changes to object when it's passed to a function via apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715287/data-type-of-pandas-column-changes-to-object-when-its-passed-to-a-function-via)

Comment: Yes, you're right, @johnDanger, but I feel like using `result_type='expand'` in @harvpan's suggestion is better.  `reduce` is supposed to function differently, and suggests something different.  I do not exactly understand how `reduce` generates the proper result.  Whereas it is quite clear why `result_type='expand'` would.

Comment: `reduce` is no longer a valid argument of `pandas.DataFrame.apply`. The above link is to show users other similar questions (i.e. this question is a duplicate). I added an answer using `result_type` to that question aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `result_type='expand'` in `.apply()` With that, list-like results will be turned into columns. You can read more in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.dtype, result_type='expand')
```

Output:

```
a     object
b    float64
c      int64
d     object
dtype: object
```

Without `result_type='expand'`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: print(x))
```

Gives:

```
0     the
1    this
Name: a, dtype: object
0      5
1    2.3
Name: b, dtype: object
0     8
1    11
Name: c, dtype: object
0    the
1      7
Name: d, dtype: object
```

With `result_type='expand'`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: print(x), result_type='expand')
```

Output:

```
0     the
1    this
Name: a, dtype: object
0    5.0
1    2.3
Name: b, dtype: float64
0     8
1    11
Name: c, dtype: int64
0    the
1      7
Name: d, dtype: object
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I get a typeerror running this code.  Which pandas version are you using?

Comment: I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917404/why-does-apply-change-dtype-in-pandas-dataframe-columns) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715287/data-type-of-pandas-column-changes-to-object-when-its-passed-to-a-function-via/31715588#31715588) but this seems to be deprecated.

Comment: Also in the future would probably be better just to flag as a duplicate, since those look nearly identical

Comment: @user3483203, I am using '0.23.0' and I am not getting any error. Which version are you using?

Comment: @user3483203, I was going to flag it as duplicates but `reduce=True` did not give me this result and I got a `FutureWarning` as well. The warning said to use `result_type='reduce'`, which did not give me the correct result either, so I worked on it and `result_type='expand'` gave me the right answer.

Comment: Thank you, @HarvIpan !  This was exactly what I was looking for!  I figured (hoped) there was an easy solution.  I have to spend a moment to understand why it's doing that (i.e., the default option for `result_type` gives an answer depending upon the type received), I still don't quite understand the default.  But this answer solved the immediate problem.  :-)

Comment: @MikeWilliamson, glad I could be of your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can store `df.dtypes` in a variable and access it later using dictionary-like syntax. This works because `pd.DataFrame.apply` passes a *named* series to a specified function.

Here's a minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['the', 'this'], 'b': [5, 2.3], 'c': [8, 11], 'd': ['the', 7]})

type_map = df.dtypes

def tmp_fn(val, type_map, typ):
    if type_map[val.name] == typ:
        print(val.name, type(val))
        print(type_map[val.name])

df['e'] = df.apply(lambda x: tmp_fn(x, type_map, 'object'))

a <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
object
d <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
object
```

Comment: This is a nice idea and a good suggestion, @jpp , but it doesn't solve my original issue.  E.g., note that it is still saying `object` for everything in your answer provided.  The `result_type='expand'` suggestion given above is the real key to resolve this.

Comment: `it is still saying object for everything in your answer provided` - actually, it only says `object` for `a` and `d`. This is because I'm explicitly isolating `object` series.

Comment: Oh, right, I see.  It's skipping them due to the `if` check.  My bad.